# Не выводится файл PDF с хоста

Tags: tcpdf

Доброго времени суток!
При печати PDF с использованием TCPDF с локального хоста (XAMPP для Windows) все замечательно, а как только выложил на реальный хостинг, вместо PDF браузер отображает сам текст. Анализ показывает, что вместо заголовка text/pdf от сервера приходит заголовок Content-Type text/html. В файле с примером вывода BOM отсутствует. Подскажите плиз где копаться...

Comment: «копаться» надо в настройках http-сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, кто принял участие, в том числе и ТП хостинга ))). Точно выловить проблему увы не получается, но скорее всего проблема с фреймворком (Yii2), поскольку тестовый скрипт, вызванный через контроллер, приводит к проблеме, описанной выше, но если его вызвать по прямо ссылке, все работает. Как ни странно, локальный Апач (windows) такой проблемы не вызывает. Думаю, вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Answer (score 0):

«копаться» надо в настройках http-сервера.

если к его настройкам доступа нет, но обрабатываются правила из `.htaccess`, то попробуйте добавить в него:

```
AddType text/pdf .pdf
```

(если тип контента вам нужен именно `text/pdf`)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но пока не помогло. Погуглил про AddType, пробовал разные варианты. Создал тикет у хостера, возможно ткнут носом /*sarcasm*/